# How to override AutoSubmitAction for sitecore workflow

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-workflow

'm trying to customize sample workflow. I would like to override Sitecore.Workflows.Simple.AutoSubmitAction with my bussiness logic but I am not getting the steps from where I can customize. Basically I want workflow from which any item change I want to change last modified date of its parent. I know we can achieve this by event onsave but I want using workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no point in overriding `AutoSubmitAction`.

Just create your custom action class and implement `WorkflowPipelineArgs` method:

```cs
public class CustomAutoAction
{
    public void Process(WorkflowPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Item dataItem = args.DataItem;
        if (dataItem != null && dataItem.Parent != null) {
            dataItem.Parent ...
        }
```

Then add it under `/sitecore/system/Workflows/Sample Workflow/Draft/__OnSave`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. You saved my days.

Comment: My custom workflow action  is not triggering under admin login. any option to trigger action